# pdf: распознавание текста

Tags: python, pdf, текст

Подскажите, есть ли какая-то утилита или библиотека (желательно для python, но не обязательно) **помимо tesseract и его использующих** для корректного извлечения текста из PDF-файлов, представляющих скан-копии документов? Tesseract очень плохо распознаёт русский язык и структуру документа. PDF-файлов несколько сотен, и вручную их обработать просто нереально.
ОС не важна.

Comment: В скан-копиях обычно нет OCR слоя, поэтому это неправильно называть извлечением текста. Нужен полноценный OCR. Вытаскивайте картинки из pdf  и используйте соответствующий OCR софт.

Comment: исспользуй программу abby fine reader. У неё кончно также присутствуют ошибки, но кроме тессеракта на питоне вариантов нет. Про несколько сотен файлов: запусти несколько копий программ и оставь комп на недельку... иных способов не вижу.